# PostgreSQL: syntax error at or near ";"

Tags: postgresql

I am new to programming and SQL. Why do I get this error while creating the table?

```
fishies=> create table vamshi( text, serial);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: create table vamshi( text, serial);
```

Comment: Perhaps you need a [create table tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_create_table.htm)? You have column types, but no names?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-table.html

Comment: I am using [create table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html). It is a bit confusing.

Comment: Where in the page you linked to did you find the syntax that leaves out the column names?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the comma between text and serial.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: I am using same link. Now I got it.

Comment: Nice to hear. You use the comma to separate fields.

Comment: The link is good, but the answer is wrong: you *do* need the comma, unless you want to create a table that has a single column named `text`, which is not what I think the OP wanted. Rather, you have to add column names.

Comment: The answer is not wrong. While the intent of OP might be that, the syntax is legal. In postgresql 9.6: `create table test(text serial);
CREATE TABLE`